# Activity is never launched

Tags: android

I am working on a music player app.
For that I have referred an online tutorial at androidhive.
I have Main Activity as **AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity** and the code is:

```
public class AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
// Media Player
private  MediaPlayer mp;
// Handler to update UI timer, progress bar etc,.
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();;
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
private int currentSongIndex = 0; 
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.player);

    // All player buttons
    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);

    // Mediaplayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    // Listeners
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

    // Getting all songs list
    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    // By default play first song
    playSong(0);

    /**
     * Play button click event
     * plays a song and changes button to pause image
     * pauses a song and changes button to play image
     * */
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check for already playing
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();
                    // Changing button image to play button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }else{
                // Resume song
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.start();
                    // Changing button image to pause button
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Forward button click event
     * Forwards song specified seconds
     * */
    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }else{
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });

    /**
     * Backward button click event
     * Backward song to specified seconds
     * */
    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position                
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
            if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            }else{
                // backward to starting position
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Next button click event
     * Plays next song by taking currentSongIndex + 1
     * */
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // check if next song is there or not
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                // play first song
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Back button click event
     * Plays previous song by currentSongIndex - 1
     * */
    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            }else{
                // play last song
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Repeat button
     * Enables repeat flag to true
     * */
    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }   
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Shuffle button
     * Enables shuffle flag to true
     * */
    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }else{
                // make repeat to true
                isShuffle= true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // make shuffle to false
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }   
        }
    });

    /**
     * Button Click event for Play list click event
     * Launches list activity which displays list of songs
     * */
    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);         
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Receiving song index from playlist view
 * and play the song
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                 int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
         currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
         // play selected song
         playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}

/**
 * Function to play a song
 * @param songIndex - index of song
 * */
public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    // Play song
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        // Displaying Song title
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        // Changing Button Image to pause image
        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        // set Progress bar values
        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        // Updating progress bar
        updateProgressBar();            
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Update timer on seekbar
 * */
public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);        
}   

/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
       }
    };

/**
 * 
 * */
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}

/**
 * When user starts moving the progress handler
 * */
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}

/**
 * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
 * */
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

    // forward or backward to certain seconds
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

    // update timer progress again
    updateProgressBar();
}

/**
 * On Song Playing completed
 * if repeat is ON play same song again
 * if shuffle is ON play random song
 * */
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    // check for repeat is ON or OFF
    if(isRepeat){
        // repeat is on play same song again
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if(isShuffle){
        // shuffle is on - play a random song
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else{
        // no repeat or shuffle ON - play next song
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            // play first song
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}

@Override
 public void onDestroy(){
 super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
 }

}
```

Whereas I have a ListActivity **PlayListActivity**, and the code is:

```
public class PlayListActivity extends ListActivity {
    // Songs list
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.playlist);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        SongsManager plm = new SongsManager();
        // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = plm.getPlayList();

        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }

        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "songTitle" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.songTitle });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();
        // listening to single listitem click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting listitem index
                int songIndex = position;

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
                // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
                setResult(100, in);
                // Closing PlayListView
                finish();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Whenever I keep AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity as the main Activity, the Song starts.
But whenever I try to use PlayListActivity as the Main Activity, the AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity, which should be launched on listclick, is never lauched

Answer (score 0):

You are not starting the activity in onItemClick. Use

```
startActivity(in)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child activity never starts because you're missing a call to `startActivity(intent)`

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting listitem index
            int songIndex = position;

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity.class);
            // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
            in.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex);
            startActivity(in);

        }
```